# onClick on RecyclerView.ViewHolder not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am following the Shrine example application appeared on Google official Codelabs ([here](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-104-kotlin#6)).

I want to create a simple view (Fragment like other Fragments) to show detail text of any item when clicked.

I think the best way to implement onClick on elements is in the `StaggeredProductCardViewHolder` class as I see it implements `RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)`.

This is what I tried already but I cannot even catch a click on any item anywhere on screen, so what is going wrong ?

```
class StaggeredProductCardViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {

    var productImage: NetworkImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_image)
    var productTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_title)
    var productPrice: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price)


    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        println("wow clicked")
        v?.context?.startActivity(Intent(v.context, ProductCardDetailActivity::class.java))
    }

    class ProductCardDetailActivity : Fragment(){

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            println("onCreate")
        }
        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            println("onCreateView")
            return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I added a Fragment `ProductCardDetailActivity` where I will be implementing other methods to show item Fragment description when clicked.

I really don't know from where to start and where to head, otherwise I would show more effort on this but I keep trying meanwhile.

Comment: Where is your adapter code? Please add the adapter code here so that we can see the issue.

Comment: You override the onClick event but you haven't written the setOnClickListener to actually call the event. At least not here.

Comment: I see, I am giving it a try like the post bellow

Comment: Does it make sense? You need to set a listener to receive the click events, so the ``View`` can pass events to that listener. By implementing ``View.OnClickListener`` and overriding ``onClick`` you've made your class work as a suitable listener - now you just have to pass it to the View to use :)

Comment: yes yes I see that I missed to attach a listener, to the object which is expected to behave somehow when clicked, and that the implementation is in onClick. ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just implementing View.OnClickListener interface.
It does nothing with handling click.
You should attach this for view holder's view

```
class StaggeredProductCardViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {

var productImage: NetworkImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_image)
var productTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_title)
var productPrice: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price)
init{
   itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
}


override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    println("wow clicked")
    v?.context?.startActivity(Intent(v.context, ProductCardDetailActivity::class.java))
}

class ProductCardDetailActivity : Fragment(){

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        println("onCreate")
    }
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        println("onCreateView")
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

}